# Minimum code to render a ribbon

Tags: 2010

What is the minimum code to render a ribbon?
I'm thinking there must be something like..

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ribbon" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<SharePoint:SPRibbon
            runat="server"
            PlaceholderElementId="RibbonContainer"
            CssFile="">
            <SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent
                runat="server"
                Location="TabRowLeft"
                CssClass="ms-siteactionscontainer s4-notdlg">
<SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent
                runat="server"
                Location="TabRowRight"
                ID="RibbonTabRowRight"
                CssClass="s4-trc-container s4-notdlg">
</SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent>
        </SharePoint:SPRibbon>
```